# Change matplotlib x-axis to include years only

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have the following panda dataframe:

[image]

When plotting a line graph using Matplotlib, the x-axis (dates) are all squashed together. As seen below:

[image]

Do you know how this can be done? I am relatively new to this and the code I have used is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df_temp['Mes'], df_temp['data science'], label='data science')
plt.plot(df_temp['Mes'], df_temp['machine learning'], label='machine learning')
plt.plot(df_temp['Mes'], df_temp['deep learning'], label='deep learning')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Popularity')
plt.title('Popularity of AI terms by date')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
```

Thanks alot

Comment: Convert mes to datetimes.  It is being plotted as strings

Answer (score 1):

```
ticks_data = [2004,2005,2006]
plt.xticks(ticks_data)
```

Or you can also try,

```
plt.xticklabels(ticks_data, fontsize=14)
```

This will replace the x axis with years, in place of `ticks_data` , you can add use a list of your choice which you may derive from the pandas DataFrame itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `groupby` to only display mean popularity for each year, 
then use `reset_index()` to convert a grouped object into a new dataframe.

```
new_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'popularity': df.groupby(df['Mes'].dt.year)['a'].mean()}).reset_index()
plt.plot(new_dataframe['Mes'], new_dataframe['popularity'], label='data science')
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Popularity")
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert Mes to datetime format, it will take care of chronology(across visualization packages) and assign appropriate x-ticks and intervals.
It does not answer your question specifically but I presume your need is to declutter your plot.

```
df_temp.Mes=pd.to_datetime(df_temp.Mes)
```